# python 3 - search and replace text file -

Tags: python-3.x

I am using a script to search and replace string on a comma delimited text file.

It works fine to replace "available" with "not-available".

```
updateBook = updateBook.replace("available", "not-available")
```

However it fails if strings containing characters like single quotes and/or commas.

for exemple:

**replacing:** 'available', '6ba8c817-d72d-4593-8914-7a40d733b6db', 'free\n'

**with:** 'not-available', '6ba8c817-d72d-4593-8914-7a40d733b6db', 'jorge'

I tried escape quotes and commas unsuccessfully.

```
updateBook = updateBook.replace("\'available\'\, \'6ba8c817-d72d-4593-8914-7a40d733b6db\'\, \'free", 
"\'not-available\'\, \'6ba8c817-d72d-4593-8914-7a40d733b6db\'\, \'jorge")
```

**Below is the code**

```
# Read in the file
updateBook = None
with open('books.txt', 'r') as f:
    updateBook = f.read()

# Replace the target string

updateBook = updateBook.replace("'available', '6ba8c817-d72d-4593-8914-7a40d733b6db', 'free\n'", 
"'not-available', '6ba8c817-d72d-4593-8914-7a40d733b6db', 'jorge'")


# Write changes to the file.
with open('books.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(updateBook)
```

Please let now if you can help. Thank you

Comment: I hope you're not re-inventing [sed](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info).

Comment: The `\n` may trip you up, since it is *inside* the closing single quote of `'free\n'`. Not sure if that's meant to, but without seeing the actual line *as read in by `f.read()`*, it's hard to tell.

Comment: If there is indeed a literal `\n` inside those single quotes, use a double backslash to escape the backslash: `..., 'free\\n``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) may help you here.  It depends how general you need the replacement to be.

```
import re


def repl(match):
    d = match.groupdict()
    d.update('one': 'non-available', 'two': '6ba8c817-d72d-4593-8914-7a40d733b6db', 'three': 'jorge')
    s = '{preone}{one}{pretwo}{two}{prethree}{three}{postthree}'.format(**d)


original_string = 'available...'
escaped_values = map(re.escape, ['available', '6ba8c817-d72d-4593-8914-7a40d733b6db', 'free'])
regex_string = r'^(?P<preone>[\'\"])(?P<one>{0})(?P<pretwo>[\'\"],\s*[\'\"])(?P<two>{1})(?P<prethree>[\'\"],\s*[\'\"])(?P<three>{2})(?P<postthree>[\'\"])$'.format(*escaped_values)
replaced_string re.sub(regex_string, repl, original_string)
```